# Can you find the treasure??

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, problem-solving

My big bro gave this problem one week ago. I could not still solve it.Please HELP.

**STORY**

A man was just looking for items in his store room. Suddenly he found a map , which showed
[image]

then it stated
That if the man goes straight from the pole(P) to house A and turns 90* and moves to M such that PA=AM.
Similarly if he goes from P to B and turns 90* again to move from B to N such that BN=PN

THEN a straight line MN is produced.In the midpoint of MN the TREASURE IS PRESENT.

[image]

**THE PROBLEM**

Now the man went to find the treasure but when he reached there he was shocked.
because the pole(P) was cut down (i.e the pole was absent from the place)

***NOW CAN HE FIND THE TREASURE????***

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

As the diagram suggests, any starting point and the endpoints ($A^\prime$ and $B^\prime)$ of the routes through $A$ and $B$ determine pairs of congruent triangles with the (other) vertices $X$ and $Y$ of the square with diagonal $\overline{AB}$. The key midpoint property then becomes clear (and nicely related to the distance from starting point to square-corner).

Now, starting at any point on the $Y$ side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, the instructions (with appropriately-oriented turns) take you to $X$ (necessarily the midpoint of $\overline{A^\prime B^\prime}$); and vice-versa. (What about points *on* $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$?) So, you should check both points, just to be sure. $\square$

Answer (score 5):

Identify the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $T$ be the position of the treasure.

If the direction of rotation is the one given in the picture, then

$$\begin{cases}
M &= A - i (A-P)\\
N &= B + i (B-P)
\end{cases}
\implies
T = \frac12(M+N) = \frac{A+B}{2} - i\frac{A-B}{2}$$

This means in order to get to $T$, one first move to the midpoint of $AB$, rotate $90^\circ$ clockwise and then move half the distance between $AB$. 
Alternatively, if one construct a square with $AB$ as its diagonal, the treasure $T$ will be located on one of the corners of the square.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. He can put down a new pole wherever he wants and follow the same instructions. He will still find the treasure.

Comment: This may be true, but it's far from obvious, and so not really a useful answer without further explanation.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. If he starts on the same side of line AB as the treasure, then he wouldn't find the treasure with these instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that he will have to dig in two places.  The places are found by bisecting the line $AB$, and on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ marking of the distances $AB/2$ from the midpoint of $AB$ in either direction.

The proof:

By rescaling and rotating, we can place $A$ and $B$ at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ in a cartesian coordinate system.  Now the pole was at some other location; say in the lower half plane at angle $OAP = \theta$ and length $AP = \alpha$. Then $$P = (-1+\alpha \cos \theta, -\alpha \sin \theta)$$ And by drawing a line of lenght $\alpha$ from $A$ perpendicular to $AP$ you find $M$ at $$M=(1+\alpha \sin \theta, \alpha \cos \theta)$$ (Actually, these formulas also work if $P$ is in the upper half plane; then $\theta$ is negative.)

Now if lenght $PB = \beta$, you can (but don't need to) determine $\beta$ as $\sqrt{5-4 \cos \theta}$.  And if angle $ABP$ is $\phi$, then $$\sin \phi = \frac{\alpha \sin \theta}{ \beta}$$ and   $$\cos\phi = \frac{2-\alpha \cos \theta}{ \beta}$$  Next move to $N$ at $$N = (1,0) + (-\beta \sin \phi, \beta \cos \phi) = (1-\alpha \sin \theta, 2-\alpha \cos \theta)$$
Finally the treasure $T$ is at 
$$T = \frac{M+N}{2} = (0,1)$$

So $T$ is at a corner of the square whose diagonal is $AB$; but there are two such corners so you have to dig in two places (unless you get lucky on the first hole).